# How to send parameter to a webmethod (web service) from iphone application programmatically?

Tags: iphone, web-services

I have develop a web service which provides the hospital names of a particular state inside a iphone application. In my application there are different states in table view. When a user select a particular state, I need to send the that particular state name to the web service so that it can display the hospitals belongs to that particular state. How can I achieve this???Please Help me. I stuck here for long time.....thanks in advance....

Comment: You should update your question to be more clear that you are trying to figure out how to retrieve the value in the iOS app and not how to pass the value to the service.

Answer (score 0):

That all depends on your webservice. If you are using a RESTful webservice you could do something like http://mysite.com?state=NewYork and the webservice can pull the state parameter and find that the user is looking for New York.

If you are using a SOAP webservice you would have to follow the schema defined in the webservice's WSDL.

Edit 1:

In either case:
In the iOS app you can determine which table row was selected by making your class implememnt UITableViewDelegate and implementing tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: ([Documentation Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)) At this point you can determine which state you are looking for and add that value to the service call.

Edit 2:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yoursite/webService"]] retain];
NSString *bodyLength =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [bodyString length]];
[request addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:bodyLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[bodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSURLConnection *myConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[myConnection start];
```

Comment: In that case you will need to provide more information. Is there a wsdl you can show? Or at least the portion of code in the service that wants to receive the state parameter.

Comment: [WebMethod]
    public DataSet stateWiseHospitalName(string stateName)
    {

        string strSQL;
        DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
        strSQL = "SELECT hospital_name from ws_tbl_hospital_details where state ='"+stateName+"';";
        myDataSet = ExecuteDataset(strSQL);

        return myDataSet;

    }

Comment: There is something before that. C# pulls the parameter our for you and passes it to your service. There is probably a wsdl so try opening a browser and going to the url of this service call then putting ?wsdl on the end of the url. You will probably see some xml and that is your wsdl.

Comment: ok...i got your point. but I dont want to hardcode the parameter....i just want to send it programtically..i mean when i select a particular state...that state should be passed

Comment: in the iOS app you can determine which table row was selected by making your class implememnt UITableViewDelegate and implementing tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: The documentation is here: ( http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html ) At this point you can determine which state you are looking for and add that value to the service call. Is that what you needed?

Comment: Can you please tell me how to pass the parameter... I am searching a lot....but not success...where and how to specify the parameter in the soap message???????

Comment: See edit 2. It sounds like the bodyString should be something like "param1=value1" but again that depends on how your service is implemented and what it is expecting.